# Update UITextField.text does not update the binding value

Tags: swiftui

I have multi TextField that allow user input numbers from keyboard and minus sign from [+/-] button. The problem is when I updated value of [editingTextField.text], displayed value in Textfield is updated but binding value [text] is not updated. How do my [+/-] button can update current editing TextField?

Thanks for any help!

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    
    @State private var showTextFieldToolbar = false
    @State private var text = ""
    @State private var text2 = ""
    @State private var currentText = ""
    @State var editingTextField: UITextField? = nil
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(currentText)
                TextField("Watts", text: $text
                      , onEditingChanged: { editingChanged in
                      }
                      , onCommit: {
                        showTextFieldToolbar = false
                      })
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
                
                TextField("Von", text: $text2) { isChanged in
                } onCommit: {
                    showTextFieldToolbar = false
                }
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { obj in
                self.editingTextField = obj.object as? UITextField
                showTextFieldToolbar = true
            }
            .onChange(of: text, perform: { value in
                currentText = text
            })
            .onChange(of: text2, perform: { value in
                currentText = text2
            })

             VStack {
                Spacer()
                if showTextFieldToolbar {
                    HStack {
                        Button("+/-") {
                            plusMinusAction()
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(.trailing, 12)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("OK") {
                            showTextFieldToolbar = false
                            editingTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(.trailing, 12)
                    }
                    .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity,
                           idealHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44,
                           alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func plusMinusAction() {
        if let text = editingTextField?.text {
            if text.hasPrefix("-") {
                editingTextField?.text = String(text.suffix(text.count - 1))
            } else {
                editingTextField?.text = "-\(text)"
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

EDIT: I update binding value in onEditingChanged event and it worked perfectly.

```
                      onEditingChanged: { isChanged in
                        if !isChanged {
                            text = editingTextField?.text ?? text
                            editingTextField = nil
                        }
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

This is the code I use to make it work. That is, text1 and text2 values are updated when [+/-] button is clicked. (ignoring currentText for now)

```
import SwiftUI


@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}

class TextModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flag = false  // true="-", false=""
    @Published var text1 = ""
    @Published var text2 = ""
    
    func toggleUpdate() {
        flag.toggle()
        update()
    }
    
    func update() {
        if flag {
            text1 = text1.hasPrefix("-") ? text1 : "-" + text1
            text2 = text2.hasPrefix("-") ? text2 : "-" + text2
        } else {
            text1 = text1.hasPrefix("-") ? String(text1.dropFirst()) : text1
            text2 = text2.hasPrefix("-") ? String(text2.dropFirst()) : text2
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    
    @StateObject var textModel = TextModel()
    
    @State private var showTextFieldToolbar = false
    @State private var currentText = ""
    @State var editingTextField: UITextField? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(currentText)
                TextField("Watts", text: $textModel.text1, onCommit: {
                    showTextFieldToolbar = false
                    currentText = textModel.text1
                })
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showTextFieldToolbar = true
                        currentText = textModel.text1
                        textModel.update()
                    }
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
                
                TextField("Von", text: $textModel.text2, onCommit: {
                    showTextFieldToolbar = false
                    currentText = textModel.text2
                })
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showTextFieldToolbar = true
                        currentText = textModel.text2
                        textModel.update()
                    }
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { obj in
                self.editingTextField = obj.object as? UITextField
                showTextFieldToolbar = true
            }
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                if showTextFieldToolbar {
                    HStack {
                        Button("+/-") {
                            plusMinusAction()
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(.trailing, 12)
                        Spacer()
                        Button("OK") {
                            textModel.update()
                            if let txt = editingTextField?.text {
                                currentText = txt
                            }
                            showTextFieldToolbar = false
                            editingTextField?.resignFirstResponder()
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .padding(.trailing, 12)
                    }
                    .frame(idealWidth: .infinity, maxWidth: .infinity,
                           idealHeight: 44, maxHeight: 44,
                           alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func plusMinusAction() {
        if let txt = editingTextField?.text {
            if txt.hasPrefix("-") {
                editingTextField?.text = String(txt.dropFirst())
            } else {
                editingTextField?.text = "-\(txt)"
            }
        }
        if let txt = editingTextField?.text {
            currentText = txt
        }
        textModel.toggleUpdate()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i want self.text and self.text2 value to be updated when [+/-] button is clicked!

Comment: I had a re-think of the code structure. I've updated the answer with  the code I use to make it work.

Comment: I just want to update the focusing TextField! currentText is only used to monitor the input value. I update binding value in onEditingChanged event and it worked perfectly.